# Issue with hover effects when using different browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, hover

I have simple site which i created with some hover effects, On Crome which i used to develop the site worked perfectly how i wanted it to but with firefox the hover effects have all changed. What could be the reason for this?

I have supplied a link to codepen for your reference: https://codepen.io/underlight/pen/LmEjBW

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Black Han Sans";
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 26px;
}
.navigation {
    color: #4cb1e6;
    font-family: "Black Han Sans";
}
p {
    font-size: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.crane {
    width: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: solid 2px #4cb1e6;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}
.bg {
    height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0%);
    transform: translate(0%);
}
.wrapper:nth-of-type(3) {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.box {
    background-color: #222;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.box img{
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
.box:hover img  {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05) rotate(2deg);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05) rotate(2deg);
    transform: scale(1.05) rotate(2deg);
    opacity: .7;
}
span:nth-of-type(1) {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4cb1e6;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-100%);
    transform: translate(-100%)
}
span:nth-of-type(2) {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4cb1e6;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .2s;
    transition-delay: .2s;
    -webkit-transform: translate(100%);
    -moz-transform: translate(100%);
    transform: translate(100%)
}
.box:hover span:nth-of-type(1), .box:hover span:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0);
    transform: translate(0);
}
span:nth-of-type(3), span:nth-of-type(4) {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 40px;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-0%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-0%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-0%, -50%);
    background-color: #4cb1e6; 
    -webkit-transition: 1s; 
    -moz-transition: 1s; 
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .2s;
    transition-delay: .2s;
    opacity: .7;
}
.box:hover span:nth-of-type(3), .box:hover span:nth-of-type(4) {
    width: 25%;
}
span:nth-of-type(4) {
    left: 50%;
}
.box h3 {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: .7;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    color: #4cb1e6;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 70%;
}
.box:hover h3 {
    -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .3s;
    transition-delay: .3s;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #fefefe;
}
@media (max-width: 740px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .box img {
        height: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class="navigation">
        <div>
            <p>Created By <a href="#" target="_blank">UnderLight Studio</a></p>
            <ul>
                <li><img class="crane" src="img/crane.svg">STACKER</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="bg">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="box">
                <a href="https://www.transnetportterminals.net/Ports/Stack%20Dates/DURBAN%20CONTAINER%20TERMINAL%20PIER%201.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/326410/pexels-photo-326410.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <h3>Durban-pier1</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="box">
                <a href="https://www.transnetportterminals.net/Ports/Stack%20Dates/DURBAN%20CONTAINER%20TERMINAL%20PIER%202.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/799091/pexels-photo-799091.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <h3>Durban-pier2</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="box">
                <a href="https://www.transnetportterminals.net/Ports/Stack%20Dates/CAPE%20TOWN%20CONTAINER%20TERMINAL.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/259447/pexels-photo-259447.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <h3>Cape Town</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </section>
</body>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looks the same to me on both browsers. I am using a mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very useful CodePen implementation - Thanks, also very interesting.

I took a brief look at your codepen project. To this extent i can see the issue and how to fix this for firefox. However perhaps someone else can add more depth and insight as to why this happens. The clear issue being the way firefox and chrome interpret and use css for animation seems to vary and while there should be a single standard working across all/most browsers, that isn't (yet) the case.

you could try my following solution which enabled me to get the codepen working correctly in both chrome and firefox (hope this helps).

separate

```
.box:hover span:nth-of-type(1), .box:hover span:nth-of-type(2)
```

into 2 classes:

.box:hover span:nth-of-type(1):

```
-webkit-transform: translate(0);
-moz-transform: translate(-100%) !important;
transform: translate(-100%);
```

.box:hover span:nth-of-type(2):

```
-webkit-transform: translate(0);
-moz-transform: translate(0) !important;
transform: translate(-100%);
```

Ive also amended the following two classes:

```
span:nth-of-type(1) {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   top: 0;
   height: 3px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #4cb1e6;
   -webkit-transition: 1s;
   -moz-transition: 1s;
   transition: 1s;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-100%);
   -moz-transform: translate(0) !important;
   transform: translate(-100%);
}

span:nth-of-type(2) {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   bottom: 0;
   height: 3px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #4cb1e6;
   -webkit-transition: 1s;
   -moz-transition: 1s;
   transition: 1s;
       transition-delay: 0s;
   -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
   -moz-transition-delay: .2s;
   transition-delay: .2s;
   -webkit-transform: translate(100%);
   -moz-transform: translate(100%) !important;
   transform: translate(100%);
}
```

Youll notice the two -moz transform attributes have been given

> !important

This means that when launched in firefox these attributes will be used over the default transform attribute. This also allows the same class to work with different values to the same effect in chrome and firefox.

Afraid my knowledge of firefox css interpretation and how it handles css compared to chrome is very little, hopefully someone else can get back to you on that or you may wish to google it and find out more yourself.

Comment: Thank you Im-Harrison, Using your answer but adjusting some of the Translate units I got the result I was looking for:) The !important tag seemed to be the key. Thanks a Million.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You Can do it more Smartly with This Code Remove Span and do it before after css :

    Css Code 

     body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Black Han Sans";
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 26px;
        }

        .navigation {
            color: #4cb1e6;
            font-family: "Black Han Sans";

        }

        p {
            font-size: 40%;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

        a {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .crane {
            width: 40px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        ul {
            padding: 0;
        }


        ul li {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 10px;
            border: solid 2px #4cb1e6;
            border-radius: 15px;
            width: 150px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .bg {
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .wrapper {
            width: 300px;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: 0 auto;
            -webkit-transform: translate(0%);
            -moz-transform: translate(0%);
            transform: translate(0%);
        }

        .wrapper:nth-of-type(3) {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        .box {
            background-color: #222;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .box img {
            width: 100%;
            -webkit-transition: .5s;
            -moz-transition: .5s;
            transition: .5s;
        }

        .box:hover img {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.05) rotate(2deg);
            -moz-transform: scale(1.05) rotate(2deg);
            transform: scale(1.05) rotate(2deg);
            opacity: .7;
        }

        .box h3 {
            position: absolute;
            opacity: .7;
            -webkit-transition: 1s;
            -moz-transition: 1s;
            transition: 1s;
            color: #4cb1e6;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            font-weight: 700;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            z-index: 2;
            font-size: 70%;
        }

        .box:hover h3 {
            -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
            -moz-transition-delay: .3s;
            transition-delay: .3s;
            opacity: 1;
            color: #fefefe;

        }

        .box h3:after {
            position: absolute;
            width: 0;
            height: 40px;
            opacity: .7;
            content: '';
            background-color: #4cb1e6;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            z-index: -1;
            -webkit-transition: 1s;
            -moz-transition: 1s;
            transition: 1s;
            -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
            -moz-transition-delay: .2s;
            transition-delay: .2s;
            transform-origin: 0px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: table;
        }

        .box:hover h3:after {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .box a {
            display: block;
        }

        .box a::after {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 3px;
            width: 0;
            right: 0;
            content: "";
            background-color: #4cb1e6;
            -webkit-transition: 1s;
            -moz-transition: 1s;
            transition: 1s;
            -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
            -moz-transition-delay: .2s;
            transition-delay: .2s;
        }

        .box a::before {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            top: 0;
            height: 3px;
            width: 0;
            content: "";
            background-color: #4cb1e6;
            -webkit-transition: 1s;
            -moz-transition: 1s;
            transition: 1s;
            -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
            -moz-transition-delay: .2s;
            transition-delay: .2s;
        }

        .box:hover a::after,
        .box:hover a::before {
            width: 100%;
        }

        @media (max-width: 740px) {
            .wrapper {
                width: 100%;
            }
            .box img {
                height: 50%;
            }
        }

    Html Code 

    <nav class="navigation">
            <div>
                <p>Created By <a href="#" target="_blank">UnderLight Studio</a></p>
                <ul>
                    <li><img class="crane" src="img/crane.svg">STACKER</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <section class="bg">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="box">
                    <a href="https://www.transnetportterminals.net/Ports/Stack%20Dates/DURBAN%20CONTAINER%20TERMINAL%20PIER%201.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/326410/pexels-photo-326410.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260">
                    <h3>Durban-pier1</h3></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="box">
                    <a href="https://www.transnetportterminals.net/Ports/Stack%20Dates/DURBAN%20CONTAINER%20TERMINAL%20PIER%202.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/799091/pexels-photo-799091.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260">
                    <h3>Durban-pier2</h3></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="box">
                    <a href="https://www.transnetportterminals.net/Ports/Stack%20Dates/CAPE%20TOWN%20CONTAINER%20TERMINAL.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/259447/pexels-photo-259447.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260">
                    <h3>Cape Town</h3></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

Working Js Fiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/bwh42eqd/`
```